# PHP Code Error. Can't find my logic mistake

Tags: php, validation, email

Ok. So this is my code below. I'm trying to follow a tutorial on webtuts about validating email. But my sample is not working out. It is supposed to alert the user that it has entered an invalid email. So what my mate did is he created the "show_warning" jquery function to allow me to display my $msg. But it doesn't work. Is my logic wrong?.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) AND
   isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']) AND
   isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) AND
   isset($_POST['role_id']) && !empty($_POST['role_id'])) 
    {
        $username = ($_POST['username']);
        $password = ($_POST['password']);
        $email = ($_POST['email']);
        $role_id = ($_POST['role_id']);  

            if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email))
            {  
                $msg = 'The email you entered is invalid. Please try again.';
            }
                else
            {  
                $msg = 'Your account has been made, <br /> please verify by clicking the activation link in your email.';  
            }     
    } 
?>
```

======================================

```
<div id="main-content">
  <div id="create-user">

      <h1>Create User</h1>
      <form action="" method="post">
      <table id="userform" width="600px" border=0>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /></td>
          <td><label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="password" name="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></td>
          <td><label for="role_id">Role</label>
            <select>
              <?php $roles = load_roles() ;?>
              <?php foreach ($roles as $role): ?>
              <option value='<?php echo $role['role_id']; ?>'><?php echo $role['role']; ?></option>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" id="submit" name="save_user" value="Create User"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pls echo $msg; to display  in browser

Comment: var_dump(filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));

Comment: Also `/[_a-z0-9]/i == /\w/`

Comment: no need use both isset() and empty() fn in php. empty() return false if  variable is not there or variable is NULL,FALSE,''

Comment: messi fan - where will i put the echo?.

Comment: good point empty explicit check isset so if you use empty there is no need to use isset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for validating email php provides

```
$email="test@gmail.com" //your email to validate here

if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

       echo "E-mail is valid";
}
else
{
      echo "E-mail is not valid";
}
```

and you must not use `eregi`. you can use `preg_match()`

for more validation function follow this link

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: @N̨ul̕L͑P̯͍̭ȏͣ͛iƞer do you know anything about mobile inbox to db using php

Comment: i tried the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL in my test file. but it doesn't output the supposed error 'email invalid'. it just saves into database. is there supposed to be an argument there? can u provide me a sample code.

Comment: Sorry! My logic was wrong it was supposed to be if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)).

Comment: @AjVillalobos ok hope you got it now :)

Comment: @N̨ul̕L͑P̯͍̭ȏͣ͛iƞer its okay i am searching on this even i asked in stack but didn't got specific answer

Comment: I solved my problem now. I didn't name my SELECT so it produces an error. But this FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL is a great addition to my beginner php skils. Thanks Yadav and Messi.

Comment: @AjVillalobos  always check php manual for function and how to use them exactly .... so you wont have problem like this again and regx you are using to validate email isnt fool prof .. check http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Thank you! Now my problem is how to send email :). The code in the tutorial site is using the mail($to,$subject,$message,$header). What if my host doesn't support SMTP?

Comment: are you sure your host not supporting smtp?

Comment: i tried the mail($to,$subject,$message,$header). i made an if statement to tell me if its sent or not, it tells me it send, but it doesn't appear in my inbox.

Comment: use swift mailer or php mailer .. and you need to have smtp server

Answer (score 4):

[`eregi()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

so its would be actual reason

AND  [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with the i (PCRE_CASELESS) modifier is the suggested alternative.

as in  answer of Yadav Chetan use `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` instead those regx

Comment: wait this is to much information. hehe. i will try one of each. ill understand first =)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email))
            {  
                echo $msg = 'The email you entered is invalid. Please try again.';
            }
                else
            {  
                echo $msg = 'Your account has been made, <br /> please verify by clicking the activation link in your email.';  
            }
```

Comment: friend eregi() is depricated